# Is it possible to restore windows 10 from empty hard drive if plenty of system restore points saved?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, hardware-failure, system-restore

Apparently my hard drive was wiped so I lost everything. I don't know if this is possible, but would the system restore points I had saved be in some other partition that I would be able to boot into? I am trying to get as much data back as possible. So if this is possible how would I restore my hard drive using the system restore points?

Comment: No; restore points are not enough.

Comment: What do you mean “apparently”? Things like that don’t happen by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Just because the hard drive was wiped, doesn't necessary mean everything is gone.  If the hard drive has not been over written there are software programs that might allow you to get the information off your old hard drive.  If you do this yourself it will be super time consuming if it is near a TB.  If you pay someone to do this I would expect it to be expensive.  If you do this you would have to attach it to a working machine that will be able to scan the old hard drive.  I have never used or heard of someone successfully restore from just the restore point.